# ZXing is not scanning on Android (Xamarin app)

Tags: xamarin, qr-code, barcode, zxing

I am using below code to scan a QR code in my Xamarin. I am currently testing it on Samsung Galaxy (Android) and I am able to view the camera streaming but it is not scanning any QR code.

How can I fix this please to get the result of the QR scanned?

```
public void Scan()
{
try
{
scanner.Options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions()
{
UseFrontCameraIfAvailable = false, //update later to come from settings
PossibleFormats = new List(),
TryHarder = true,
AutoRotate = false,
TryInverted = true,
DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 2000,
};

    scanner.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
    scanner.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

    // scanner.IsVisible = false;

    scanner.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
    // scanner.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX);
    // scanner.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.EAN_13);


    scanner.OnScanResult += (result) => {
        // Stop scanning
        scanner.IsAnalyzing = false;
        scanner.IsScanning = false;

        if (scanner.IsScanning)
        {
            scanner.AutoFocus();
        }

        // Pop the page and show the result
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
            if (result != null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Scan Value", result.Text, "OK");
            }
        });
    };

    mainGrid.Children.Add(scanner, 0, 1);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    DisplayAlert("Scan Value", ex.ToString(), "Error");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the wrong event handler, or missing an event, also the camera never focuses:

the condition is never true, due to this fragment of code:

```
    scanner.IsScanning = false;

    if (scanner.IsScanning)
    {
        scanner.AutoFocus();
    }
```

Comment: I tried also below code but did not scan anything: scanner.OnScanResult += (result) => {

    if (scanner.IsScanning)
    {
        scanner.AutoFocus();
    }

    // Pop the page and show the result
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
        if (result != null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Scan Value", result.Text, "OK");
        }
    });
};

Comment: try diffing your code example with working example code online, or downloading a working project so you can figure out what's different.

Comment: Simple working example for Android here - https://github.com/jhealy/xammutts/tree/master/ZXingPlaySLN/ZXingPlay

Comment: @JoeHealy the provided repository doesn't work at all, you get null crashes because it's expecting a result that is doesn't have set yet...